# Using Gradle with OpenJDK 1.9

Tags: gradle, react-native, java, gradlew

I cannot seem to use Gradle with OpenJDK 1.9.

When I run the following command:

```
react-native run-android
```

I end up getting this error.

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '9-internal'.
```

Running java -version shows me:

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Hope this will be useful: https://blog.gradle.org/java-9-support-update

Answer (score 2):

Which version of gradle are you using?

```
cd android
./gradlew -version
```

I think there was a bug determining versions for java 1.9 which was fixed in Gradle 2.10.

Another option is to try spoofing a `java.version` that Gradle can parse

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Djava.version=1.9'
react-native run-android
```

@see [JavaVersion.java](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/base-services/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/JavaVersion.java) and [JavaVersionSpec.groovy](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/base-services/src/test/groovy/org/gradle/api/JavaVersionSpec.groovy)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an incompatibility with your build of OpenJDK 9 and Gradle.

Your OpenJDK version is:

```
openjdk version "9-internal"
```

And it appears Gradle can't parse it:

```
Could not determine java version from '9-internal'.
```

Looks like gradle is [prepared to accept `9-ea`, but not `9-internal`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/f001402c8b7f404c923d972f1bc524b2de7b3fcd/subprojects/base-services/src/test/groovy/org/gradle/api/JavaVersionSpec.groovy#L63).
You will have to modify your build of OpenJDK to have it return "9-ea" or something similar for `java -version`.

The following configure options when building OpenJDK 9 should do the trick:

```
configure \
  --with-version-pre="ea" \
  --with-version-opt="" \
  ... your other options ...
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same exact issue and, in my case, it worked by removing OpenJDK:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/openjdk-*
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt-get update
```

and installing the Oracle Java SDK:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

I know this is not the exact answer (using Gradle with OpenJDK 1.9), but I managed to keep going and run the app both in a virtual device and in my smartphone. Hope it helps.

Note: I am running `react-native: 0.40.0` and `react-native-cli: 2.0.1` in `Ubuntu 16.04`